# Is there any way to create a function that takes as argument a member function or a member?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, member, member-functions

I have a function like this:

```
void f(std::ofstream& ostrm)
{
    auto a = Myglobal->getData1();
    ostrm << a;

    auto b = Myglobal->getData2();
    ostrm << b;

    auto c = Myglobal->m_data1;
    ostrm << c;

    auto d = Myglobal->m_data2;
    ostrm << d;

    //...
    auto z = Myglobal->getData1000();
    ostrm << z;
}
```

Is there any way to create a function that takes as argument a **member function** or a **member** to factorize this code?

(`a`, `b`, `c`, d and `z` are not the same type)

Comment: Have you look at CLang API ?

Comment: How bout macros :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. One way is to turn `void f` into a function template, then pass the pointer to member of the desired data member or member function and let [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) (C++17, `<functional>` header) do the rest:

```
template <class PtrToMember>
void f(std::ofstream &ostrm, PtrToMember m){
    ostrm << std::invoke(m, Myglobal);
}

// call like this:

f(someStream, &T::getData1);
f(someStream, &T::m_data1);
```

where you should replace `T` by the the type of `Myglobal` of course. The nice thing about `std::invoke` is that it automatically handles all member (data or functions).

Comment: BTW, I don't see how there is a factorization between `f(someStream, &T::getData1);
f(someStream, &T::m_data1);` and `someStream << Myglobal->getData1(); someStream << Myglobal->m_data1;` (which can even be `someStream << Myglobal->getData1() << Myglobal->m_data1;`) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Well... fair point :) `f(someStream, &T::getData1); f(someStream, &T::m_data1);` is 57 characters, and so is `someStream << Myglobal->getData1() << Myglobal->m_data1;`. At least this solution doesn't require more typing. But now when you want to `std::format` before `<<`-ing it to the stream...

Answer (score 6):

The [*@lubgr*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427341/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-function-that-takes-as-argument-a-member-function-n/58427507#58427507)  has explained the use of `std::invoke`. One step further you can reduce the entire lines of code to a single line, using *[fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)* from [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

```
template<typename... Mems>
void f(std::ofstream& ostrm, Mems&&... args)
{
    ((ostrm << std::invoke(args, Myglobal) << " "), ...);
}
```

and you will pass the desired members or member functions to the function at once, instead of calling many times.

```
f(obj,
    &MyClass::m_data1, &MyClass::m_data2, &MyClass::m_data3,
    &MyClass::getData1, &MyClass::getData2, &MyClass::getData3);
```

**([See live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U75jAHOVLavvolTN))**

---

And providing one more template parameter in the function `f`(for the `Class`), you can make it completely generic code and no global variables needed.

```
template<typename Class, typename... Mems>
void f(std::ofstream& ostrm, const Class& obj, Mems&&... args)
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    ((ostrm << std::invoke(args, obj) << " "), ...);
}
```

and now in the `main()`

```
std::ofstream ostrm{"test_file.txt"};
const auto obj{ std::make_unique<MyClass>() };
f(ostrm,
    obj,
    &MyClass::m_data1, &MyClass::m_data2, &MyClass::m_data3,
    &MyClass::getData1, &MyClass::getData2, &MyClass::getData3);
```

Comment: This is awesome! One might only argue about the readability though. Buy once in pointer-to-member-land, readability isn't necessarily the ultimate goad anyway.

Comment: @lubgr Yeah. However, the `std::invoke` nowadays saves a lot, especially from the era of `(obj->*mem_function)(arg1, arg2,...)` to simply more readable `std::invoke(mem_function, obj, std::forward<Args>(args)...)`